# How to Specify Source Time Zone When converting between two Time Zones

Tags: c#, timezone

I'm working with the following Time Zone code:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime sourceDt = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-09-05T08:00:00");
DateTime sourceUtc = sourceDt.ToUniversalTime();


var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var tzTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sourceUtc, tz);
Console.WriteLine("Time1= " + tzTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


var tz2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var tz2Time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sourceUtc, tz2);
Console.WriteLine("Time2= " + tz2Time.ToString("hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Time1 outputs 07:00 AM and Time2 outputs 08:00 AM.  I'm assuming this is because I'm in EST. Is there a way I can specify that what time zone sourceDt is in?

For example, I would like sourceDt to be in CST and have Time1 output 08:00 AM and Time2 output 09:00 AM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` method to convert a local time to utc time while specifying the source time zone.

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var tz2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

DateTime sourceDt = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-09-05T08:00:00");
DateTime sourceUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(sourceDt, tz);


var tzTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sourceUtc, tz);
Console.WriteLine("Time1= " + tzTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

var tz2Time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sourceUtc, tz2);
Console.WriteLine("Time2= " + tz2Time.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

> Time1= 08:00 AM
> Time2= 09:00 AM

Comment: I just tested it and it works just like you said. I tried setting the first one to Pacific Standard Time and it worked correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime doesn't contain timezone information, it only has a [Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=net-7.0#system-datetimekind-unspecified) property which can be either of UTC, Local or Unspecified.

> Is there a way I can specify that what time zone sourceDt is in?

So the answer is no, if you want to have Time1 output 08:00 AM, just create a datetime like this:

```
var tzTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-09-05T08:00:00");
```

What you can do is assume that this datetime is in the CST, and then deduce a local time in the reverse direction:

```
var sourceUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tzTime, tz);
var sourceDt = sourceUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

In fact if the Kind property of a DateTime object is unspecified, you can assume the datetime in any time zone as you wish.